# Today's and tomorrow's date in YYYY-MM-DD format in PST timezone in python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to get the date for today and tomorrow in YYYY-MM-DD format in python in PST timezone. The datetime() returns date in UTC. I have an internal JIRA system which uses PST date setting and i want to query that. The code will run in a restricted environment where i can't install any external python modules like the pytz library. I tried in a lot of ways but am unsuccessful.

Is there anyway it can be done in python?

Comment: The documentation for datetime.today() state, "Return the current local date."  Right now it is the 20th in Greenwich, and datetime.today() in Colorado returns 2014-03-19.

Answer (score 3):

There is confusion about the timezone for datetime.date.today(), http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html  It gives local time.  Right now it is the 20th in Greenwich, Google:

1:55 AM
Thursday, March 20, 2014 (GMT)
Time in Greenwich, London, UK

In Colorado today() gives the 19th:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.date.today())
'2014-03-19'
>>> str(datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(1))
'2014-03-20'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can use timedelta for converting UTC to PST and todays date to tomorrows date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=8) //convert to PST
print datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1) //get tomorrow
```

For  ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ format, there is a date.isoformat() method in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code to get today's date and tomorrow's date in PST.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

/*Timezone aware object*/
utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
pst_now = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles"))
file_dt=pst_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(file_dt)


curr_time=datetime.utcnow().astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
tom_time=utc_now+datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today=curr_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
tomorrow=tom_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("Today is "+today+" and Tomorrow is "+tomorrow)
```